# In Pascal's triangle without the $1$s, what is the sum of squares of reciprocals?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Consider Pascal's triangle without the $1$s.

[image]

Let $S$ be the sum of squares of reciprocals.

$$S=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\cdots$$

> Does $S$ have a closed form?

Wolfram [does not evaluate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BSum%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29nCk%5C%2841%29%2C-2%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) $S$.

### Significance of $S$

$S$ is a single non-trivial number representing all of Pascal's triangle without the $1$s. (The sum of *unsquared* reciprocals diverges because the harmonic series diverges.)

### Why I suspect $S$ has a closed form

I suspect $S$ has a closed form, because many other infinite sums of reciprocals in Pascal's triangle have closed forms. Examples:

- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\binom{k+2}{k}^{-2}=\frac43\pi^2-13$ ([source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B%5C%2840%29k%2B2%5C%2841%29%21%2Ck%212%21%5D%5C%2841%29%2C-2%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D))
- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\binom{k+3}{k}^{-2}=9\pi^2-\frac{355}{4}$ ([source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B%5C%2840%29k%2B3%5C%2841%29%21%2Ck%213%21%5D%5C%2841%29%2C-2%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D))
- $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}=\frac43+\frac{2\pi\sqrt3}{27}$ ([source](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf)).
- In Pascal's triangle without the outer two layers, the sum of (unsquared) reciprocals is $3/2$, as I show below.

### Showing that $1<S<2$

Consider the color-coded Pascal's triangle below. (The green and orange numbers extend below the diagram infinitely).

[image]

Let $T$ be the sum of reciprocals of the blue and green numbers. I found that $f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\binom{n+k}{k}^{-1}=\frac{2}{n^2-1}$ for $n>1$ ([source](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/BinomialReciprocalsInPascal.shtml)). Then $T=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty f(n)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2-1}=\frac32$ by telescoping.

So the sum of reciprocals of the green numbers is $\frac32-\left(\frac16+\frac{2}{10}+\frac{2}{15}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{2}{21}+\frac{2}{35}\right)=\frac{67}{84}$.

So the sum of *squares* of reciprocals of the green numbers is between $0$ and $\left(\frac{67}{84}\right)^2\approx 0.6361961451$.

Using the [fact](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html) that $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$, the sum of squares of reciprocals of the orange and blue numbers is $2\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\right)-\left(\frac12\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{2}{10^2}+\frac{2}{15^2}+\frac{1}{20^2}+\frac{2}{21^2}+\frac{2}{35^2}\right)\approx 1.105202601$.

Therefore $1<S<2$.

### Edit

In the comments, @Tyma Gaidash shows that $S=\frac23-\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt3}+\int_0^1\frac{t(t^2-3t+1)\ln(t(1-t))}{(t^2-t+1)^3}dt\approx 1.1146$. I have asked about a closed form for the integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4828954/398708).

Comment: $S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n>k}{n\choose k}^{-2}$. Perhaps it's possible to find a closed form for the inner sums first? Using partial fraction decomposition they can be written as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of sums of the form $\sum_{n>k}\frac1{(n-m)(n-j)}$, where $0\le m,j\le k-1$ are integers.

Comment: We use [hypergeometric $_3 F_2$’s integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/03/). Summing over the first sum gives $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{_3F_2(1,2,2;n+2,n+2;1)}{(n+1)^2}$ and applying the integral representation experimentally gives $S=\frac23-\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt3}+\int_0^1\frac{t(t^2-3t+1)\ln(t(1-t))}{(t^2-t+1)^3}dt\approx 1.1146$

Comment: Using the @ТymaGaidash's work alongside [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828985/515527) result, your sum can be written in terms of the [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) as:

$$S=\frac13+\frac{4}{3\sqrt 3}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$

Comment: Naturally one has to wonder whether the generalized variant also has a closed form:
$$S(n)=\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{5^n}+\cdots$$
Perhaps if an integral is found then it is easily doable.

Comment: I have asked about the [general case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4829462/398708).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the comments:

@Mastrem notes that $S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n>k}{n\choose k}^{-2}$.

@Tyma Gaidash notes that, using [hypergeometric ${}_3F_2$'s integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/03/), summing over the first sum gives $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{_3F_2(1,2,2;n+2,n+2;1)}{(n+1)^2}$. Applying the integral representation experimentally gives $S=\frac23-\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt3}+\int_0^1\frac{t(t^2-3t+1)\ln(t(1-t))}{(t^2-t+1)^3}\mathrm dt$ (which is supported by numerical evidence using [A024746](https://oeis.org/A024746)).

@Zacky uses a [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828985/398708) to yield $S=\frac13+\frac{4}{3\sqrt 3}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$ where $\operatorname{Cl}_2(x)$ is the [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function).

### Edit:

Thanks to @Tyma Gaidash's comment to this answer, we have:

$$S=\frac13+\frac{4}{3\sqrt 3}G\approx 1.11463574623$$

where $G$ is [Gieseking's Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GiesekingsConstant.html).

Comment: $\text{Cl}_2\left(\frac\pi3\right)=G$ which is [Gieseking’s constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GiesekingsConstant.html)