# In Pascal's triangle without the $1$s, what is the sum of $n$th powers of the reciprocals?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Consider Pascal's triangle without the $1$s.

[image]

Let $S(n)$ be the sum of $n$th powers of the reciprocals, where $n$ is an integer greater than $1$. ($S(1)$ diverges because the harmonic series diverges.)

$$S(n)=\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{5^n}+\cdots$$

> What is a closed form for $S(n)$ in terms of $n$?

[Earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4829024/398708) we found that $S(2)=\frac13+\frac{4}{3\sqrt 3}G\approx 1.11463574623$ where $G$ is [Gieseking's constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GiesekingsConstant.html). This question seeks to generalize this result.

Using the [first 150 rows](https://oeis.org/A014410), here are rough approximations:

$S(2)\approx1.101346$
$S(3)\approx0.286888$
$S(4)\approx0.103181$
$S(5)\approx0.042758$
$S(6)\approx0.019085$
$S(7)\approx0.008890$
$S(8)\approx0.004249$
$S(9)\approx0.002064$
$S(10)\approx0.001013$

Wolfram [does not evaluate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5B%5C%2840%29Sum%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bm%21%2Ck%21%5C%2840%29m-k%5C%2841%29%21%5D%5C%2841%29%2C-n%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cm-1%7D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bm%2C2%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) $S(n)$.

Comment: Using the same method as in the previous post, $S(3)$ has [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIiYG.jpg) integral representation. We may need another method instead. However, $S(n)=\sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty{_{n+1}}F_n(1,2,\dots, 2;j+1,\dots,j+1;1)j^{-n}$ using the [hypergeometric function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html). There may be a “closed form” using a [special function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html) defined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR4Vg.jpg)